# Is there a way to use AWS Amplify library (JavaScript) to access s3 bucket without cognito user poool and identity pool?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am trying to make use of amplify library (JavaScript to access s3 bucket with temporary access key and secret access key generated by STS. But it seems like i need to have a cognito user pool and identity pool.

```
import Amplify, { Storage } from 'aws-amplify';

Amplify.configure({
  Storage: {
    region: 'ap-south-1',
    endpoint: "http://localhost:4572",
    bucket: 'mybucket',
  }
})

Storage.list('photos/').then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Is there a way to achieve that without using AWS SDK?

```
[WARN] 56:56.803 AWSS3Provider - ensure credentials error No Cognito Identity pool provided for unauthenticated access
No credentials
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS SDK for javascript that uses AWS API under the hood. In this case you need either make s3 bucket public / open to everyone or use AWS IAM credentials which is not a secure way.

Comment: I am planning to make use of AWS STS to generate temporary AccessKeyId and SecretAccessKey. And the reason i want to stick with amplify is because it is providing me easy/clean way to configure access level at blob level and also functionality like upload and download progress, etc,

Comment: But that's also not a secure way. You need some criteria for STS to decide who will be able to access resources.

Answer (score -1):

It's generally not recommend to use IAM credentials directly in Amplify, because rolling your own authentication/authorization (the process of deciding to grant STS credentials or not) is dangerous.

However, there are plenty of valid reasons for doing it, so here goes: [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/3116#issuecomment-515024286) is about this issue, and says you can do it via code like

```js
AWS.config.update({
  credentials: new AWS.Credentials({
    accessKeyId: 'the key',
    secretAccessKey: 'the other key'
  })
});
```

before your `Amplify.configure()`

Comment: Still getting the same error. Am i doing something wrong ??
`import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import Amplify, { Storage, Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

AWS.config.update({
  credentials: new AWS.Credentials({
    accessKeyId: 'the key',
    secretAccessKey: 'the other key'
  })
});

Amplify.configure({
  Storage: {
    region: 'ap-south-1',
    endpoint: "http://localhost:4572",
    bucket: 'mybucket'
  }
});

Storage.list('/').then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err))`

Comment: Also facing the same issue, did you find a solution ?